# como fazer um desenho svg ter o tamanho só do perímetro e não de um quadrado, como é o normal

Tags: html, html5, svg

Eu tenho uma imagem vetorizada (SVG) criada no Inkscape, porém, ela fica com um tamanho (padrão ?) que é quadrado (as dimensões), mas eu quero que a imagem tenha apenas o tamanho do seu perímetro, e não simplesmente largura x altura.
Exemplo do vetor do estado de São Paulo:[image: aqui]

Então, preciso que o vetor ocupe na tela exatamente o espaço do contorno da imagem e não  um quadrado com as extremidades.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg3732"
   width="682.66669"
   height="682.66669"
   viewBox="0 0 682.66669 682.66669"
   sodipodi:docname="SaoPaulo.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata3738">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3736" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="706"
     id="namedview3734"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.34570311"
     inkscape:cx="341.33334"
     inkscape:cy="341.33334"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg3732" />
  <image
     width="682.66669"
     height="682.66669"
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIAEAYAAACk6Ai5AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdC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ek9
YwenjgG/g8v33vtZfR+zmJngf+v19Q+GvS8U7sq7EAaf89bl91eCt477ZtyHT0PWtNT+Gc9C2DXs
E74HLGEzq8Ad42a6chDfFWxMTIPFmzddufKAn6p357hFrvlPP685cftDG1rC1iNz3t0xFqKn+kdF
 vj5YQuK9XAwjCC3/AS1j5rdUmqlNUlCH7Otc9xzOZfl8C1LMoXEgggDx4x5xX1yyrXTeds9QV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 abBfromgTRPztIKgevGReh0oQTiFcE9ZcADL2cM3IMuLnvIyxH2etPR+aXj0UXpoyl6QoaKV
2ANaezlEuiDPV8Gh4dPAulOLtwhQbdU8NRCMlWqOIcBe1zLUVgS8qllH23PB9crx16IbwZVm9wJv
XYT44JSiD3qAa47exKVB4B6fz/yrQP5iwVcijkCJzyJeL7wSvOdaI+01IOnrjPOp20FuEP5iCNCc
SOrw87IY4hP6iVlgrFNzDDvcHvJgZMwxcMzRN7oGg6wktggBag+XOfb/fI4+2PAGkQNfAkGVU1NU
e8h7Njhv+FLwfs32o9dD0LsYffSfcHcc2CHgvPdkvy2Q+EzaD0lH4VKH2C7XK0D02ofLYitCyr1M
a/ob4H3AOsr+POQZGtQk1xIo/lr42oJvQtib/qVDqkFyaoYjNQmMDaqyugXyWXFC5AO1i4scIruj
wmT6TwhA6UvQAas2gBKc49h3p6hHDVGifQVSEYRobf1fU2vjD+pb8/aesKv3mH+qK9RkMpn+FMwO
AI8Lnabd29QYi/qML4UFlxhPNAcYSyueM3paLrBdVeYZ13f0FL3JXz2BICoRt24CabjICF2ICwfK
aOPOTa73ZGs2/E2m34MLHR3IiT9BwGbOsBf0nsaLxh6wrJR1tBDwes4WYQ8A7a44KkeDeFU0Eb1B
jVLfqNmgZxhFjOGQMdV5KPMY6NFGmN4b5DdylWzGz4+oxSAaia5gG2/BOhVEgFgl7gL13EOkjelq
jHEHHP6uTs4koAc1aQskkU4qnnUMyR7JkP0kXaDAVtpywloP5BVRRC4ArFiwgHpL5VS7IbOR65Kj
OVCJgpQE8hJMBNCehbwC+ofGDCMdbK21BpYxYN9g3WyfBjKHaCH2g3hJNBTdQI1UX6iZYNRWzY3P
IH2HMyPTCq6a+tf6MdA+l8tlXaAJpakNJJBKIv96lPVQ/AkB5rCVj0F2EINkOtgSLd9Y/YBtXGA/
iM8ZwLvgbKIHupzgchiz9AXAYvd68kTzkNjfyD9rCkAEQYQCr/IlM8DW0nLD2gG0F8Ro6QNqNUfY
COqh6qrCwTHXZXfOAPUOm9RyoDCh5Hvs88iKXZCbIMKAV/iMyWDtrbWzzAVLLxmqXQE1me9ZAHzI
j2oVZL7rsjing4pRHVUO3B085UGUJoIiYAxQVrUS1F5VR6WBfbH1S9tgsBWxHLJVAVlGbBIOoCEl
qQ2qpnpL9QR9rnFbzwHp9Z1LMxeCcdZYa5QCuVQukdWAALzww718XybZIy+uEMcNEDN4TowE22yL
xfoOyPpit/ADtZXz7Hts/78n67p1en7fKpCPkuD4xBXq/BCMK+oHozIwhWcZCnzEbtaA3s143vgR
LIb2ujYAvKtave3pINeKlbIeiLdEZzES1Hy1TX0Oxhn1rSoBGTWdlTJfBud9Pdr1A2ivySkyJ/AR
fZgOXOc+0YANzWz4m35fumdOv/YyebnI9cVe3KE4BV7OdN8Za6+WKjF+Yqs2+ntPuqQmk8n0e/uf
7QA432FK5uY5IGZK3SiOFwXYziUy+I69YrRowR6GIrV9tGM79VzJYprooz5sc159rCZx7YtKpKNI
90tHYMNmjHDXpJzjyT7Vk/r+e6UzmUz/L8+QcILxIQDozwomgPGOyqv2Ai+o5WoscIN47pD9xPcz
0U/MAjlWxIoGwBy6MBa4TwoPALtn7nwqGaSBel/lV4eALzjMetwNIxcwiub0BdFPXBHlyH5CrVAo
shuWhue1zdMR8IBUkjz5HgC+5ThbcTdIHcAoWtIXxKvilqgJPHRvj0R68nMfJxBv/IDivEELMJap
EsY5YKbayGIgmgfEAsWJoBCwSPQWU0COEDdFDdxzsN8GHpDGI/7zZdWy6iWrIT2Wb3gX1OeqtLoE
BLk/JxXlbqjKUPGVuAfE8x4HcQ9Fv80/fsLr8AQZLEQoeUGtVRXULVBdWMSrIMIJ9Aw5j6AIiNfF
XVEPqEQBSgPJ7s8VDYkkO5p81tyEMHdHhtqkqqk4UN1ZzGsgcuJHEFCB/JR6LN9I8lAMSMNBOtkd
FY8HRXSA2q/qqzRQl2it7MB6dYpdwENP/VelEGWBDWKoWAxykrgvmgEvU58uwCPSSebXIzKyGuxZ
MR9uksBdUNNUmNoJajNn2QPCU/8/n+ffI35OBQJUqmfZxREiWtQCxtGal4EYHhH/2HmGuEcM4Pkc
jLkqn3EAGKw+Zxpw2f25k48QIoAJoi2DQPYXV2Q54BST+QFIIu03z9Nk+t3py92p9iKJXMD6/mF8
KId6tbr7e0F7XvY2mqqc+mclTk+s1LrSPwpRajKZTH8e/3MdAJc6Tdu1oTHCVYBl2ldowpueai0u
UZoHKkJOl4P5SH3POWYY49hgrDJ6y4fig8H1uM0JeL8lLgKwyZVIXChjMwBK5vVkbzb8TSaTyWQy
mZ5q+gfuVBskqpGMvhx1HD+0vp77Ym1EbFHneO+W+pyGYrJo+D93t2wymf7K/vJBAE9bp0zdfB2s
JWU+NRqbcY8fceCQR9ilOhBHW0qpN7UVqpCoKd7UR+jfMF087+0rKsuPVeH5NmLJB313YxCA1eiF
xImhWgMCfm74p3tSs+FvMplMJpPJ9PRSQEkUVhSoJJLxzWNjuiiKe1xAbgxVPeIVcTCj9M8Lml57
0oU2mUym34t80gX4o5y/Nz1g4z40qWl5jeng/Fb6kp9cLCdelZen6cBNtVNaucAtbPoI8b4K4nK5
BKGrxarK/vrEUITyfTNJR2DRGwMulNwCCBCzPIfJCgrj/aTP12QymUwmk8n0DwmUbINE96yWEsad
Qo8oqH5UtX1aUkCNUzWNLuqUZb7qytmLdWZu3jz0SRfZZDKZfj9/+hEAlxZNUusqgd7cEmGtjpDK
Oz6jAcKYEhDpaoKunbgXZXkkW1s6Gr1Ub751XOVVbbZh53X1Ag7LAusHMo8eMtKKZIdaMLkrDopx
02srCidCX4dEILQXPIfr6UldntT+pM/fZDKZTCaTyfQvEGIqCvfdnA86YcW9OUohOaFwQSrQWl05
C1EEiGGypGyS8qWrgiHZC2DGAjCZTH9+f7pZTddfX97/wFFIHxE94MFsNKfVtVAdRbce94q1RlJF
7DOe1cfK/gwVk1iGr3yDkWKBcYsDRh45gDeMBmKUXqZuJIOoQ+M5qSRRivtVrhOIFaexBR0DSRTu
HuIhnsNmNfizwhL96erNZDKZTCaTyQTAfXewP30NGgqhDaIQD0gddVmEcYGg2cUxCCfJQsC21E7q
KxdJx/2CqAMlB46r0/qVJ118k8lk+vc99SMALv0w6+6WAwhXyYz2Tj+01Jgb+eK349Les823dCbB
Vtl2SoRqs8Q0o4XrGeM15SMS5Q7jGGEUJIHm6oBKokOJk+oDcUsfNWk/0IU7XUYhCSVO1iMAA12P
Q0chZXlAoERzz+EzPKnXk64Hk8lkMplMJtPvIti9hoUIQnnWxoiiFMldauhtbFec1WcnWTukXPat
4Gr9KN6vh6MxVWmqHDRloWf/zH//0CaTyfRkPbUxAC7IaZM3TgFjeYa/azR2OULcFBNxaS9bt2kd
xQY2KoOJfKc5nMedCbpLG5c2M32NyklZlabulvtBjFC5VJOPvdUG/NXkEz4EE8qjbusII5RQQnHi
QhkvYKCQWi73UUW45/BZCyWZDX+TyWQymUymvxaJQKGkxIkNqUYRymV8qiRousPb2vzZfcantjhH
a/aI0SqVZtpGgZHHawGZF9dOq7s5wxwJajKZ/rye2i+wi/Wm/bhRw0IZsZlJuFRd3iaQZDVH3VbB
+NNb1eeWb2dRUEwWDZrNwI6iZv9zBHCHPU3zEEwmiZbKuLBgVW8hMZDGsygUhrbGs37xJM/hnJ7U
+u+W12QymUwmk8n0p+IZ6am8UQgQilTSiTvxPSnqAg1r72C7MvBLn8+LYi6ZHGasOEBhattmWG5Y
1+EsUnTM2KbNnvRpmEwm0z/v6Z0CkIcqxiOUqqcS5WXZnQw+577hL97luHi33g9I0Z5Bq0qRk7PE
5ymCwpcNTMaCgWQjTjTs+ng0DJT2LQpQ2lhPw3/sL472tDX8s0YgZMUceM+dqDR3l40Kds9dU81Q
gOBlBKDUWtydOqdwL3OTw72bqIJAIBnqrgcx2/P+Nne+4idPmuQ53jueVHnSp7ajyGQymUwmk+nf
5Ln/E8o9JUAfjz+CvBWnkVc0EoWHHcdfXFYvzIRDvM09LZcqyCWjkO50THJJR8mf76Nd/3YJTCaT
6b/sqW3YXWwwzdiwn87qtNK0TxlHCK04Q3m+Eu2NaT+CD3Gk11cYCKRLAAZKLHU3WbWj7gYxH3qy
+2WD+knLalj/MppsUQQCpZ9EoRC8iQCEfAWFQIminj1TPPv6IbF4xi8oLIDCiQQUVs+nq3vqwsDp
qQH3+wJJBmDBwAuFC0EPBAJD7w4IBOfceYg77vLIg4BAscZT3qwpE+ZqCCaTyWQymf6sPCNBVQqg
QASTiA1b4jvYxVjOVA/FgmR/1AtY1W5yi2RxUJ3SFyt/dYoCWgyUem9C61bBT/o0TCaT6R97ekcA
xLNRNpNFRQmxUYUY5SkruuBXzUflVnXxrp/KfXTS1R40LBjyEQYSlD8CBa6q7lSkuBvMciQAQpwF
QDHBc5SsYH9/9JPu7A4I95Hc5cDYhkSAautu+GuHceDAqqWioaEzFxeCDGVHIx2fe5cIR0PcGkYG
Ocm4eYoL7BbP3w1AYVEbkgZSnMHcyrhHIMu5r3VCUIl73kewE8nzOT7kHMncCvfGiwRi8m9FEUWO
8BzYCCY958c4UfhorQEHLoqiI9EohhWJE4mBjjRuAQJh2N2dCfI+BiDkCM95vutJQ/9L9WsymUwm
k8n07/I8IBLu4IBSv0cQLh4GjSJE7abhrD4UUVuM0PagRBPRXwzhqBxoe1WVJV3Vcd3hiief9Cd9
IiaTyfSPPLUNsgv3pr2/cZ1WDCsGD/XLaIRTf/B+Yojh0DtnSCEdp1YLL9IJsZbBigW4goHAoCg6
FqR7RhfgRKBwYEMisBkb3EPhDX8UCkQeT3XEeNIET3rQU5ysWAFZQQH/XoM264m+9GzlGVKvfBAo
hLEVAUjZDpAYYjs6GUB9UhBoqbcpgB/ee5ciiKfytjUkEkf1vee4TSIHL0tLiv8c67oHQi+U3t9V
ltJ6hnOcbudWZLUJTdoUI+Xv1eeZadPXb2hAgPd3FJY7CAotl3LLK5xbdzv59kpfFZJOVUZzuaBV
VKcvJ0u3USdZyHN1VhLLLZxV9pBGLgJKf4AdL1K8t2Jg4GI2LhRWRuKNhpPN7lrQP0dHYWG6pzq2
e6qrnqc4RX+zvkwmk8lkMpmenKzVny667/SM2ygc+Mi2ohFW9vUqrO6yk/Irr3OZQti1DtQQ34ru
+rfkIl1FYSl1aVxmq2BzSoDpr+GG9Z0m374IaQ/Ti/skYmGkWsW7uLRYLcVoRTd1iDexi4/VRXKy
QM7mHimc5TW8iaAuIzhPLpYaH6ittBSnVW0iGaN6s1/M4CLl0GhCN06jl/pwfIdWzz/ps/3f8dR2
AFw8PL3ChleoJGZRTX3FcWI5LN7zSja2qM/FV/4l+BovrgZXxIv2bMjzqugGHC+5BB+eQS/trS5i
xavEZzhxkl7iCA58KZB7EhlkcNeyHisSC+exYANKoXABLtyzwKwIDAw+BDSEMcPdUaAWeIqX1cPr
6SjA4UlDAFCkY6CwiBPuMRZyIk4sKMbiQCeFTxFYyXW2LXlwEbg0kMJEsXPt1Pim8dO85t4qHDQw
aJejFd286ngVcOXgR6OLq4l2mRi1T7yr6hLHRxyinGwiuvAG3USsyuAebzGJ47xBMVqRwCjycBMH
u0Qx1nKTT1Rf1ZH+6jqVVXm+pb6IUx+LgSQRyHAclOIbrMZVcqsjlOGwyqWuc4KytBNFZYY4Jt/m
szwPxEuMIbraWrWRaTRuMkTUpzn76nupAzwgX4lSgMJLHsUHK4/YiQIkjQAXhnEaiYZQM3Evt+iO
UYBMwD0pYbanHj2rMjw1UzZMJpPJZDL979A9sZYWY0NiiEEkkIL1zgJqsYorlV3Kppbgihsucor5
lBG9rdWNHq5raqVLt4yxvYUqufaNGy2u/fzAyGR6Kp0fN3XUutvARHFeew3hm5TZIsAHldLZ3ujh
V/hpV9Uwy3V64yXaqYUyUy1hF9VFKzVGGXK1cYC+dFKL1Gy8eEAaAbbvrK0dHUjK7OZY6FUQH/G+
+ETVJU3WkDn0rrIws1VpGaRmq+bcJ1J1wI8SnMdX6nKZHkBqibVviDYJ//Fpmf6Bp7YD4F917u1R
jz4ejZSEdi5UiwqyrC0swJfjqlPqjXub7G+rA6qmqlToCKdBUfostdA5FhnKFWJoXXY/OakOJRfj
TSKP8qwgEz/8ggMRJOMSP2DHAtzyfJXn/5sazP56d2EAFj7HjiSR50lBoVJepCQPSd79GkeZyrXF
IXpelhnFN/0ouqq1xgZXd/aLMfSkjNitblgj5R3hLa6oe2IJOj4cVArBCaqrWQSxlZvKT1TmMCHE
qD4qUzQniTPsw5t0kaDFq2o46aUXVDOQnBY1uYWNs2KonIyf+p496lt8aauSeI9iLKAOXcVtSjGU
KNGbDBKIFCc5QTEeEa7yiUDQG+NFKgbNxHV68Alt+FLcM6JZLwqqubyqDVYbVJy2MnIra5CqY/3q
+GDD1qwaLiS5a6xH4Y/KuZlM0nCxDoVAoyXu6RHRCCzoxlAMFBir3Qv0aEXcsQdEF0/9TvOkvp7U
nFpgMplMJpPp95b1BN8CCIS+GR0dl9aCWHJybeVG6hkDxFe9WotWopSqLtsYmy3XxXtGnHzdNdQY
zllKi7HiB9JL9hsf2irqSZ+O6X+dUpPUJAVRPazlavRGWG4Ye9SnKDVWxBkaIa5popZWnk/UJNqq
BVITIxgouov7NJDNuKA7GJVWTO1iJIknDwdk8kjkiOyTUV4Eqi/9J2TeLnKGMewTAQ0NdZVEtuVa
jT+R9InuyT7Rhcn75/ncT9npXytqVvpDn1qpi7nJW8JhrBcNsKofRRN1HYnEwLtk7IRaLY+ZU2n+
aE9tw+lii2lnNlbEQjGsaiEuylFcvM1C1Zr1RIqrHCWTODEXGx8zmO9EC3y4K/KqdegEi7rqPkfU
Mh36qHG8rtLEYArijZf6XNRVD8lQzfVoeZpCGS87fjIOcV3WF53FdTHIa43XOFE5PJMAutM0ohv7
2E618GYU4FtGFnyNfMyiYK5JlOcKTQJ7iYoEMsN6n3TSKJhqV99Qgi6x34p1SHZFDVItycnIkx/Y
O2XUMXpGB1jCM7tIF7lSiwZKzvIdI3nIWC2GYxQkt1HQskWrq9dRA4wENVh7j6OqqsrFdTTf0t5G
Sj30fK+NONi58+9f35cHvBmw8RJk3rItoR5SxYtQdRzD2l2fKSayQOUngr4iv+hDex7KteoTJJ/i
75jHTkdPffXe/t737nsTVz81IyT3ad5Q9ZkhpjPDOlaFqj45XmSD8KF1tX5qjnqLL5puog7XKFd3
KD4UJVfZdDK4S4A9H35YUXxCBi4EfRBY0RmAhkDqe1EYKE64Sy3nu1dBEA09HTGVPadjTi0wmUwm
k8n0n8qaEhCHwABjMgIbXnK5qEoIjm7T1HoOc+XLCdzFh/vaMNULQx3T3xdlRSKLsJQ6Pm5l6zzm
lADTf8fFiGmujVFgfGNE2lojsMme6fmQop246RyKzkVVwKsYOteIJk0m0J5nRG3xkf6i6GV00Ddb
K7huWxbzQEtWz9ibc854XezSF8m5+g6td+arZT8hjBIMa9lOBBGHaJOkLmLnfpXnkQSRx14BHQMX
BZEIrNwgA4hzRXMEG43XvStWEiE2D4lTeShH5ztf0JytdBLbxKfMUKNVUwoDZbCUXDI+oVUu8/fm
j/LUdgD8sy4+nF524wcIsVPkE+Eo7qsvVTuC1VTVm0H0UHt4TdznJXR2k0vkYy9RqoZcSx5yUpvi
YhgzOK9mGyudj1hotNNWWZJUKfqohhQU67CWbD3B2upKVnTYf+yCZfpzm5YAn6hwtQcfriIIIo1D
jBAfCAfPsEO9Jvuwj/Ic1Fs79xk1M/LTQ74rmlsvIS21ZVVLf4ySYeMmtRzwpGsXznWapDbfAm25
9bAag5AfYWMJykhRY0QlCrBPrDYKMUUFM0L8JFeRE2gsVjKYSDXbULK3nG+5qsJUP+OC6zxVtdna
MH0ZR7hv7JBhMt01Ss0Tgwve4Q4LqFjvazqTmx11V1OW+vjV+ZAULpOz2D4eoXCKEdjwxsIBdFwo
amLFgq7q4kKhGVUAhWKau2NAPnQv6yPuek6nlCf196TmCAKTyWQymUx/z+P3CQJUVwycKPEl4eTH
O/qAyEEPfGocIVTkIfrOMHVdXSVMzLdkhu5ToWqIvuchQkOUfHZMq1bFzSkBpt/Hhfkztm//BOig
p2X0R8hRsq/2CtK1QJSQIQTKIH2VnkA8j0Q3ympNcTKd2VyQjWSS65FeXh9sFLL3I10tFe3ESHZr
vfT3jD5Wi6olvzHmVzrPbQrzWduJ5OQqVVsvIB+lcZa5j4NU0i0lyMQbX/Zg+XlVMRdOY4J7uXVV
HwBDxCJRWKmCE4Ehh1AQSc6jPcU+EhlUv759juGrRaQNyLwiz+gthK9apG6IZSqVN0QZZUWWOjL+
k1YHfrVqmu    sh1pwppxg3yaXcmTp9zBJ8S2+5jFjCXm8/gtG8oi3goH+pds5O96CTPYjtcoiK4P16feoqzNF/03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=
"
     id="image3740"
     x="0"
     y="0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Amigo edite a pergunta e coloque o código da sua imagem, pode ajudar a te responder. Falo do código `<svg>` que está dentro do arquivo .svg ok

Comment: Cara parece que na verdade vc está usando um Base64 dentro de um SVG, eu não recomendo isso, procure outro conversor de PNG/SVG ou então importe o PNG no Illustrator, rasterize para Vetor e depois exporte como SVG. Vc ainda pode usar ferramentas online e free como o OMGSVG para otimizar esse código e dar uma limpada nele. Leia tb o comentário que te respondi na minha pergunta, pode te ajudar

Comment: Tb fiz um **EDIT** na resposta, para vc ver que eu dupliquei o Path que eu já tinha e depois ajustei mais para cima para um fica "encaixado" no outro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara acho que vc pode estar confundindo um pouco os conceitos. O SVG sempre vai ser "quadrado" pois ele está dentro do [`viewbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox), agora o `path` ou `circle` [etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element#Graphics_elements) que está dentro do `viewbox` não precisa ser quadrado, pois eles são definidos pelos *anchor-points* que definem o contorno do elemento.

Para entende melhor veja essa imagem, eu coloquei uma borda no SVG que tem o `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` e `width` de 200px. Repare que eu tb tenho dois :hover, um no `SVG` e outro no `PATH`. no `SVG` eu troco a cor do `background`, e no `PATH` a cor do `FILL`, pois ele é construído dentro do viewbox do SVG e aceita códigos SVG como `fill`, `stroke` [etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Presentation)... Então repare que em uma todo o SVG é uma "área ativa" do `:hover`, já no outro o `:hover` só funciona no `path`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```css
svg {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
}
svg:nth-child(2):hover {
    background: red;
}

svg path:hover {
    fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M30,76q6-14,13-26q6-12,14-23q8-12,13-17q3-4,6-6q1-1,5-2q8-1,12-1q1,0,1,1q0,1-1,2q-13,11-27,33q-14,21-24,44q-4,9-5,11q-1,2-9,2q-5,0-6-1q-1-1-5-6q-5-8-12-15q-3-4-3-6q0-2,4-5q3-2,6-2q3,0,8,3q5,4,10,14z" fill="green" />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M30,76q6-14,13-26q6-12,14-23q8-12,13-17q3-4,6-6q1-1,5-2q8-1,12-1q1,0,1,1q0,1-1,2q-13,11-27,33q-14,21-24,44q-4,9-5,11q-1,2-9,2q-5,0-6-1q-1-1-5-6q-5-8-12-15q-3-4-3-6q0-2,4-5q3-2,6-2q3,0,8,3q5,4,10,14z" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

**EDIT**

Usando dois `paths` dentro do mesmo SVG para "encaixar" um no outro.

Usando os dois primeiros valores (`d="M30,56` e `d="M30,76`) vc controla onde inicia o desenho do `path` e vai ajustando para casar um no outro. No caso eu deixei o `eixo X` iniciando na mesma referencia em relação ao `viewbox`, já no `eixo Y` eu desloquei o `path Vermelho` mais para cima um pouco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
svg {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M30,76q6-14,13-26q6-12,14-23q8-12,13-17q3-4,6-6q1-1,5-2q8-1,12-1q1,0,1,1q0,1-1,2q-13,11-27,33q-14,21-24,44q-4,9-5,11q-1,2-9,2q-5,0-6-1q-1-1-5-6q-5-8-12-15q-3-4-3-6q0-2,4-5q3-2,6-2q3,0,8,3q5,4,10,14z" fill="green" />
    <path d="M30,56q6-14,13-26q6-12,14-23q8-12,13-17q3-4,6-6q1-1,5-2q8-1,12-1q1,0,1,1q0,1-1,2q-13,11-27,33q-14,21-24,44q-4,9-5,11q-1,2-9,2q-5,0-6-1q-1-1-5-6q-5-8-12-15q-3-4-3-6q0-2,4-5q3-2,6-2q3,0,8,3q5,4,10,14z" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: então , Hugo eu entendi tudo que vc colocou (bem interessante isso!), mas no meu caso  preciso mostrar uma imagem SVG que quando aparece várias vezes, sobrepondo uma aparição a outra, fica mostrando o espaço em branco de uma sobre a outra (mesmo com remoção de fundo). No caso do SVG do estado de Sao Paulo, que já editei pra colocar, como eu faço pra aparecer só o path. PS: criei essa imagem a partir de um PNG, com o Inkscape. A propósito, porque o Inkscape faz um arquivo de SVG (a partir de um PNG??) tão grande, e com tantas variáveis/atributos. Edite e coloquei o SVG obtido do Inkscape.

Comment: @Fernandes usando os dois primeiro valores do viewbox vc consegue "deslocar" os elementos que estão dentro dele `viewBox="X Y 100 100"` no eixo X/Y. Mas no seu caso acredito que o ideal e já gerar o SVG completo. Tipo assim, em vez de gerar um SVG para Rio e outros SVG para SP, vc já gera um SVG só com RIO e SP dentro! Outra forma e colocar todos os SVG com position:absolutem dentro de um container com position:relative e usar `top` e `left` para posicionar os elementos até juntar um no outro. Pelo que vi do código ai o Inkscape gerou um *base64* `data:image/png;base64` e não um path svg